Trouble Resizing widgets in Custom Tkinter when going into another page
I was trying to use the set_widget_scale function to resize my widgets based on the resolution of the window, when I resize the widgets on the main page it works fine when the resolution is chosen, when I go to the other page it raises this error:
("_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!ctkoptionmenu.!dropdownmenu"")

import customtkinter as ct

class App(ct.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Test")
        self.geometry("640x480")
        self.Page1()

    def Page1(self):
        for i in self.winfo_children():
            i.destroy()
        self.page1 = ct.CTkButton(self , text = "Page 2" , command = lambda: (self.Page2() , self.Resize()))
        self.page1.pack()
        self.menu = ct.CTkOptionMenu(self)
        self.menu.pack()


    def Page2(self):
        for i in self.winfo_children():
            i.destroy()
        self.page2 = ct.CTkButton(self , text = "Page 1" , command = lambda: (self.Page1() , self.Resize1()))
        self.page2.pack()
        self.menu = ct.CTkOptionMenu(self)
        self.menu.pack()

    def Resize(self):
        ct.set_widget_scaling(2)

    def Resize1(self):
        ct.set_widget_scaling(0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

This is an example of my problem that I am facing

Is the menu a must? I tested some variations and find it being the culprit. destroy + ctkmenu causes the error

I know that is the problem and I tried multiple things about it. And yes it is important because I use it to select specific options in applications

This method avoids using destroy constantly. Instead, it uses frames to separate pages. You can destroy the frames when not used, as demonstrated by the added destroy button.
import customtkinter as ct


class App(ct.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Test")
        self.geometry("640x480")

        self.end_button = ct.CTkButton(self, text="DESTROY")
        self.end_button.pack(padx=10, pady=30)

        self.page1_frame = ct.CTkFrame(self)
        self.page1_button = ct.CTkButton(self.page1_frame, text="Page 1", command=self.show_page2)
        self.page1_button.pack()
        self.page1_menu = ct.CTkOptionMenu(self.page1_frame)
        self.page1_menu.pack()

        self.page2_frame = ct.CTkFrame(self)
        self.page2_button = ct.CTkButton(self.page2_frame, text="Page 1", command=self.show_page1)
        self.page2_button.pack()
        self.page2_menu = ct.CTkOptionMenu(self.page2_frame)
        self.page2_menu.pack()

        self.page1_frame.pack()

        self.end_button.configure(command=lambda: (self.page1_frame.destroy(), self.page2_frame.destroy()))

    def show_page2(self):
        ct.set_widget_scaling(0.5)
        self.page1_frame.pack_forget()
        self.page2_frame.pack()

    def show_page1(self):
        ct.set_widget_scaling(2)
        self.page2_frame.pack_forget()
        self.page1_frame.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

I combined the resize and page functions, but it works even when using
command=lambda: (self.resize_small(), self.show_page2())
hope this helps

I tried the code you just gave me and it works just fine, I will try to use this logic on my other application and then get back to you on the results, and thanks for putting the time to help much appreciated!!

@MohammadAliNaanouh I Hope it helps, don't forget to accept my answer

@EletronX It finally worked!! And you already know I will be giving you that accept
